# Jsonify Flask: Contenth length does not match with message body size

Tags: python, http, flask

I have a problem trying to return a data in json format with jsonify ().
Use postman to do a post request to my app, and my program returns the header with a contet-length: 99
But when I copy the Json message in raw data and measure the size of the message in notepadd ++ the size of the body message
is 106.

I can't explain why that happens.

```
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/hola', methods=['POST'])

def some_function():
  
    
    payload={"Protocol":"jsonP","Packets":[{"Id":ID_P,"Message":"OK"}]
 
    return  jsonify(payload)
```

Comment: Any chance that pasting in to notepad++ is adding carriage returns?

Comment: @DaveW.Smith     No, I copy and paste directly from postman RAW data.

Comment: If postman is pretty-printing the JSON that the flask app is emitting, that would add characters.